# Why does my Gazebo GUI look completely different from what I see in the docs?

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to get started with Gazebo, so I installed Gazebo Garden on Ubuntu 22.04 and opened it alongside a basic tutorial. The GUI I see on my laptop looks completely different from what I see in the docs though. The first two images below are what I see. Below that is what I find in [the docs](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_b&tut=guided_b2). Are the docs old and am I seeing the new UI? Or what am I doing wrong here?

Also, in the About window I see I've got version 7 Garden. As far as I understand Gazebo Garden is the last version, but I also see versions up to 11, so I don't understand how I can have Garden (the latest stable version) and version 7 (I guess a very old version). What's wrong with that?

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

From the docs:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/29146/why-does-my-gazebo-gui-look-completely-different-from-what-i-see-in-the-docs?/) by [kramer65](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/189148/kramer65/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo 11 is a version of old Gazebo, now known as Gazebo-classic. The new Gazebo used to be called Ignition, but due to trademark reasons, it has been renamed back to Gazebo (see https://community.gazebosim.org/t/a-new-era-for-gazebo/1356). The latest version of the new Gazebo collection is Garden and contains the simulator `gz-sim` v7.x.

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2023-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0